# Using react-native with babel 7 with babel-preset-typescript

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I would like to use react-native with babel 7, so I can also use babel-preset-typescript.

Here is a minimal repository (which I am trying to make work): https://github.com/adrienharnay/react-native-init-typescript

Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: interesting PR about this https://github.com/artsy/emission/pull/991

Comment: Thanks, it is fairly easy to set up with React, but I think it is impossible to do with React Native for the moment